# int works fine, but causes some jerky motion... Number causes strange behavior in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Heads up, I'm pretty new to this whole thing, so if I use some incorrect verbage, I apologize.

Do `Number` data types cause problems when creating classes?  I have a `class` called `Asteroid` and when it is instantiated, I declare some properties that I assign values to at run time such as `.zVelocity`, `.xVelocity` and `.yVelocity` for example.  When they are declared as `int` data types, everything compiles and runs fine, but I run into some jerky motion when properties are altered through my trigonometry functions.  So I changed them all to `Number` data types and suddenly something very strange happens... the `Asteroid` instances no longer load to their correct `.x` and `.y` coordinates when the `.swf` is run.  Instead, the all load to the origin of the `stage` object in the top left corner.  If I change `.xVelocity` data type back to `int`, then all the `Sprite` objects render along the top of the `stage` horizontally. I hope this is making sense.  I could upload the file, but I'll need a little guidance on that.

```
package {

import flash.display.Sprite;

public class Asteroid extends Sprite {

    var xVelocity: Number;
    var yVelocity: int;
    //var zVelocity: Number;
    var velocity: Number;
    var factor: uint;

    public function Asteroid(): void {

        //xVelocity = Math.floor(Math.random()*6)-3;
        //yVelocity = Math.floor(Math.random()*4)-2;
        //zVelocity = Math.floor(Math.random()*4);
    }
}
}
```

and my Document `Class`:

```
        //////
        //    TIMER
        //////
        timer.start();
        timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerFunction);
        timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, timerComplete);

        function timerFunction(e: TimerEvent): void {
            //trace("length: " + asteroids.length);
            if (asteroids.length < 1000) {
                newAsteroid();
            }


            for (var i: int = 0; i <= asteroids.length - 1; i++) {

                asteroids[i].alpha -= .05;
                asteroids[i].x += asteroids[i].xVelocity;
                asteroids[i].y += asteroids[i].yVelocity;
                //asteroids[i].z += asteroids[i].zVelocity;
                //asteroids[i].zVelocity += .1 ;
                //asteroids[i].xVelocity /= 1.1;
                //asteroids[i].yVelocity /= 1.1;

                if (asteroids[i].alpha <= .05) {
                    asteroids.splice(i, 1);
                    removeChild(asteroids[i]);
                    i--;
                }

            }

        }

        function timerComplete(e: TimerEvent): void {
            trace("stop");
        }


        //////
        //    Asteroids
        //////
        function newAsteroid(): void {

            for (var i: int = 0; i <= 100; i++) {

                var idx: int = Math.floor(Math.random() * colorArray.length);

                asteroid = new Asteroid();
                asteroid.x = (Math.random() * stage.stageWidth * .5 + stage.stageWidth * .25) as Number;
                asteroid.y = (Math.random() * (stage.stageHeight - 100) + 50) as Number;
                asteroid.graphics.lineStyle();
                asteroid.graphics.beginFill(colorArray[idx], .6);
                asteroid.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 5, 5);
                addChild(asteroid);
                asteroids.push(asteroid);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

}

I'm probably missing something really simple.  Oh, and feel free to offer advice on any awful habits you see me getting into, but to fully correct my code is probably beyond the scope of this single question, although any attempts will be received warmly.

**Edit

The jerky motion was solved with by implementing the answer marked as correct below!

Comment: Hmm that's odd, should work with Numbers just the same way. But regarding the jerky motion - it might be due to the fact that there are 1000 half-transparent vector drawn asteroids, that's a lot to draw :) Also it naturally depends on the framerate and the timer interval (looks like you move them based on a timer?)

Comment: @neal-davis Your code looks fine. In all cases [`Math.floor()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Math.html#floor()) returns an integer ... That code should work without any problem using `Number` or `int`, I tested it with both types and it's working fine. Try to clean your project, close and reopen it in your IDE and compile again ...

Comment: @Philarmon Yes, they move based on a timer.  The frame rate "smoothness" is not the jerky motion I'm seeing, though.  I will update my original post with a further explanation of exactly what ends up being "jerky".  I know it may be a totally unrelated question to the main question of my post, but it may actually be rooted in the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

int types have a default value of 0 and that's why they work in your case but the downside is that they do round up all their value to integer which causes weird effect in animation.

Number types have a default value of NaN (not a number) and that is why you are having a lot of trouble.

You never give your variables a default value (you never instantiate them), in the case of int that works since they start at zero but in the case of Number that doesn't work since they start with NaN as default value. You keep trying to use those but they only return NaN all the time and nothing works.

I'm guessing by now you know what to do but in case:

Give your variable a value before using them!

Comment: That was it!  I feel so foolish :)  But I guess that's what learning feels like some times.